# Web API - Simple Post model with collection property is not binding

Tags: asp.net, .net, jquery, asp.net-web-api

```
// Server-side Model to bind

    public class CurrentPipelineRequest
    {
        public List<string> Usernames { get; set; }
    }

// Controller

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CurrentPipelineByMilestone(CurrentPipelineRequest currentPipelineRequest)
{
    //.....
}

// Jquery/Ajax

   var model = {
            'Usernames' : JSON.stringify(["me", "you", "I"])
        };
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/Dashboard/CurrentPipelineByMilestone'
        data: model,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
});
```

Currently, the controller action parameter "currentPipelineRequest" will be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `stringify` the whole model instead of only `Usernames`:

```
var model = {
        Usernames : ["me", "you", "I"]
    };

$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/Dashboard/CurrentPipelineByMilestone'
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
});
```

Comment: I swear I tried that in previous attempts, oh well, thanks, it's working now :)

Answer (score 2):

Binding in ASP.NET Web API is not exactly same as ASP.NET MVC.

However in ASP.NET Web API as the body content is treated a forward-only stream that can only be read once. Hence in case of complex signatures on Actions you need to specify from where you expect the parameters.

if you are getting the parameters form the body change the signature to :

```
public HttpResponseMessage CurrentPipelineByMilestone(
      [FromBody] CurrentPipelineRequest currentPipelineRequest)
```

if you are getting the parameters from uri change the signature to :

```
public HttpResponseMessage CurrentPipelineByMilestone(
      [FromUri] CurrentPipelineRequest currentPipelineRequest)
```

if you are getting the parameters from uri and body then change the signature to :

```
public HttpResponseMessage CurrentPipelineByMilestone(
      [ModelBinder] CurrentPipelineRequest currentPipelineRequest)
```

Here is an article for trying to [implement MVC style binding in Web API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/18/mvc-style-parameter-binding-for-webapi.aspx). Please note that I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  In my case, it seems that leaving the action parameter without an attribute worked, as long as I was stringifying the javascript model properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually because you're doing a POST and not sending your model through as a JSON object, so the service can't understand it.

Try this:

```
var model = {
            'Usernames' : ["me", "you", "I"]
        };

var data = JSON.stringify(model);

$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/Dashboard/CurrentPipelineByMilestone'
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
    }
```

});